# Can I Migrate An iSCSI Initiator Name To Another Server?

Tags: linux, iscsi, open-iscsi

I am working on upgrading a virtual appliance in a datacenter and the upgrade process is a drop-in replacement of an update VM, but also a different disto (Debian -> CentOS). I am stuck waiting on an admin to reconfigure the SAN for the new VM's initiator name before I can move forward with testing. I want to know if I can bypass this by reusing the old server's initiator name on the new server, or if I should avoid this like the plague.

1. Will this work for properly identifying the new Virtual Machine to the SAN?
2. Will this cause any problems (assuming that they are not both online
   at the same time)?
3. Is there any issue in the initiator name format being for a different OS? Stating debian instead of redhat?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out as I was impatient to wait on the admin required to make the change. I was able to connect to the iSCSi targets and see the disks, whereas I did not see them at all without the correct initiator name.